# How to create custom wordpress gallery

Tags: php, wordpress

Youtube link for make it easy to understand : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9by-igzg6Ms

I just need a group of images in wordpress so i could link images with next one. I am not professional in Wordpress, i am getting a problem while creating custom wordpress gallery plugins, please help me if any one can it's last day of my project and i have tried most of articles, stackoverflow question and answer but got nothing related to this.

Here is code also i am getting issue while more page button but that might be because i haven't created page for that.

```
function add_gallery_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
$a = shortcode_atts(array(
    'gallery_name' => '',
    'sub_gallery' => '',
    'per_page' => 4,
        ), $atts);

$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => $a['gallery_name'], 'posts_per_page' => $a['per_page'], 'paged' => $paged);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

?>

<?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php echo '<div class="thumbs">' . wp_get_attachment_link(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail') . '</div>';

endwhile;

echo '<div id="nav_next_previous">
<div id="next">' .
    next_posts_link('More »', $loop->max_num_pages) . '
</div>
<div id="prev">' .
    previous_posts_link('« Previous', $loop->max_num_pages) . '
</div>
</div><!-- thumbs-nextpage-wrap close-->';}
```

I am also attaching youtube video link how it will be looks like, i don't know how i can create link for next group of images. if there will be any free plugin for that will be also helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`next_posts_link` and `previous_posts_link` are used inside the loop for getting next or previous single post link.

You have to use [paginate_links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) function instead of `next_posts_link`

e.g.

```
   echo paginate_links( array(
      'format' => '?paged=%#%',
      'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
      'total' => $loop->max_num_pages,
      'prev_text' => '« Previous',
      'next_text' => 'More »',
   ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but when i click on image it just open in new window but instead of new window i want in same window, i am using wp_get_attachment_link

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_link` do not add any target attribute. so check in your code, may be any JavaScript or filter adding this attribute to your link.